# Python 3.3 cannot run this code because it does not have pygraph is their a simple way to install pygraph or can I ammend the code in some way

Tags: python, python-3.3, pygraph

Python 3.3 cannot run this code because it does not have pygraph is their a simple way to install pygraoh or can I ammend the code in some way. As you can see I think the rest is fine. It is just the one rather major issue

```
# Import graphviz
import sys

# Import pygraph
from pygraph.classes.graph import graph
from pygraph.classes.digraph import digraph
from pygraph.algorithms.searching import breadth_first_search
from pygraph.readwrite.dot import write

# Graph creation
gr = graph()

# Add nodes and edges
gr.add_nodes(["Portugal","Spain","France","Germany","Belgium","Netherlands","Italy"])
gr.add_nodes(["Switzerland","Austria","Denmark","Poland","Czech Republic","Slovakia","Hungary"])
gr.add_nodes(["England","Ireland","Scotland","Wales"])

gr.add_edge(("Portugal", "Spain"))
gr.add_edge(("Spain","France"))
gr.add_edge(("France","Belgium"))
gr.add_edge(("France","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("France","Italy"))
gr.add_edge(("Belgium","Netherlands"))
gr.add_edge(("Germany","Belgium"))
gr.add_edge(("Germany","Netherlands"))
gr.add_edge(("England","Wales"))
gr.add_edge(("England","Scotland"))
gr.add_edge(("Scotland","Wales"))
gr.add_edge(("Switzerland","Austria"))
gr.add_edge(("Switzerland","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("Switzerland","France"))
gr.add_edge(("Switzerland","Italy"))
gr.add_edge(("Austria","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("Austria","Italy"))
gr.add_edge(("Austria","Czech Republic"))
gr.add_edge(("Austria","Slovakia"))
gr.add_edge(("Austria","Hungary"))
gr.add_edge(("Denmark","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("Poland","Czech Republic"))
gr.add_edge(("Poland","Slovakia"))
gr.add_edge(("Poland","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("Czech Republic","Slovakia"))
gr.add_edge(("Czech Republic","Germany"))
gr.add_edge(("Slovakia","Hungary"))

# Draw as PNG
dot = write(gr)
f = open('europe.dot', 'a')
f.write(dot)
f.close()
import os
command = '"C:\\Program Files\\Graphviz 2.28\\bin\\dot.exe" -Tpng europe.dot > europe.png'
print(command)
os.system(command)
os.system('europe.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `pip install python-graph-core` or `easy_install python-graph-core` - if this doesn't work then you will need to download it from [here](https://code.google.com/p/python-graph/), unpack/zip it and in the resulting directory run:

```
python setup.py install
```

or

```
python3 setup.py install
```

You will need to do this for both -core and -dot packages.

If you are doing it this way you will need to ensure the dependencies, (pydot and pyparsing), are met in your installation.